# How to add a Service Reference to a service application

Tags: c#, soap, service

I am developing a service application in C#. I want to consume a SOAP service to my service application. when i build my service project, there is no problem and successful build is done. but when i start the service, the service is stopped and the message for stopping my service, in EventViewer of windows is about data types and class of soap service.

but my main question is that, Are there necessary cases for consuming a soap service in a service application in C#????

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question whether you'd already added a reference to a SOAP-service or not. If not, then you can do it the way it's described here: [How to: Add, Update, or Remove a Service Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652(v=vs.120).aspx).

The order in which I usually do it:

1. Build the project with a SOAP-service
2. Run it
3. Add or Update a reference to the SOAP-service (while it's running) into my other projects, that consume it
4. Build and run all projects

Every time the interface of your SOAP-project is changed go through the sequence  above again.